# Composition of measureable function with continuou function in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I was wondering, for general knowledge, if this claim is correct.

Let $X=L^2[0,1]$, $f\in X$, $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ invertible. Particularly, it's image is $[0,1]$ so everything is well defined. Specifically I'm interested in $\sqrt x$ so if you could also answer about this one specifically, but it is also interesting for general functions.

Is $f\circ g \in L^2[0,1]$?

Thanks so much

Comment: I would still like an answer for $\sqrt x$ if anyone could. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}\in L^2$ and $g(x)=x^2\in C^0$. Then $g(f(x))\not\in L^2(0,1)$.

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, then $f(g(x))=f(\sqrt{x})$. We have

$$\int_0^1 f^2(\sqrt{x})dx=4\int_0^1 f^2(y)y^2dy.$$

Since $y^2\leq 1$ we have $\int_0^1 f^2(\sqrt{x})dx\leq4\int_0^1 f^2(y)dy<\infty$, because $f\in L^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example!
About the other question, I think that the right identity is $L^p\subset L^q$ for $q<p$. And also, I don't quite see how the result for $g=\sqrt(x) $ follows from this identity. I would if $f$ was $\sqrt(x) $ but not when it's $g$. I'd like some help if you could. thanks!!

Comment: Oh yes, q<p. Sorry, i made a mistake.

Comment: The second thing I said doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I see. thanks though

I would still like an answer for $\sqrt x$ if anyone could.

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions:
1) If this argument works for any $g$ with bounded inverse, why wouldn't it work for $g(x)=x^2$ as you already showed?
2) How could I justify using the chage of variables rule?

Comment: No, it's false. :)

Comment: For the change of variable you can see the abstract theorem here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution.

Comment: I will re-edit for the last time. Thanks for the conversation.

Comment: What we need is that the derivative of the inverse function of g is bounded.